# Adding program booting options to the OS

Tags: boot, 12.10, startup

I am building a flight simulator box, off of Ubuntu 12.10, but I am trying to make the OS essentially invisible, I just want the machine to boot into the Flight Sim, which, that part isn't really that difficult, just a matter of adding a startup item, but I would like to make it a bit more seemless, and in-addtion to that, I would like maybe a 3-5 second countdown where you could opt-out of the flight sim from starting, if you need to troubleshoot the OS, or the flight sim itself, and I have no idea how that would be accomplished

Comment: Ideas: turn on quiet splash in grub, use a shell script that relies on user-input (dialogue box) to start the flight sim.

Answer (score 2):

Write a short shell script which is in your autostart (you seem to have solved that bit). The script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo launching in 5, press ctrl+c to abort
sleep 5
myFlightSimCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 (new installation) the work file for auto start may be owned by root! All other users have no write right, so no registration of new auto starting programs will ever take place through the user desktop.

Do change the ownership with the following terminal commands:

1. login to root account

   > ```
   > su
   > ```
2. move to startup directory

   > ```
   > cd /home/"username"/.config
   > ```
3. change owner for directory and embedded files

   > ```
   > chown -R "username" autostart
   > ```
4. you are done, close terminal, enjoy :-)

   > ```
   > exit
   > ```